# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "action_text_rich_texts" does not exist | Rails 6 | Rails_Admin | Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-admin

I've setup `Rails API` only project with `Postgreqsl` database.

**Rails Version:** `6.0.0.rc1`

**Rails_Admin Version:** `2.0.0.beta`

I am getting following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "action_text_rich_texts" does not exist LINE 8: WHERE a.attrelid = '"action_text_rich_texts"'::regclass ^
```

**P.S:** Some says Rails_Admin works fine with API only project too.
Source [Link](http://www.carlosramireziii.com/rails-5-api-mode-admin-framework-compatibility-chart.html)

**UPDATES:** I also tried by creating a new Rails project and not used `--API` flag. but error still persist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why but rails_admin is looking for a relation between action_mailbox and active_text, run `rails action_text:install` then migrate and it should solve your issue.